# Can a variable be both an object and undefined at the same time?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm mocking `chrome.storage` using jasmine's `spyOn` function like this:

```
this.fakeChromeStorage = {};
chrome = { storage: { sync: {get: function() {}, set: function() {}}}};
spyOn(chrome.storage.sync, 'get').and.callFake(function(key, callback) {
    callback();
});
```

But then when my application calls:

```
console.info(chrome.storage);
console.info(typeof chrome.storage);
console.info(chrome.storage.type);
console.info(typeof chrome.storage.type);
```

It prints:

```
[object Object]
object
undefined
undefined
```

How is this even possible?

Comment: Because `chrome.storage` is an object which has an undefined `type` property? I'm not sure what's confusing about this.

Comment: Its confusing because I thought `.type` is the way you express `typeof`

Comment: Not at all. `typeof` is the only thing that calculates the type. `.type` here is just a random property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `chrome.storage` is an Object, `chrome.storage.type` is a property on the object `chrome.storage` which does not exists and therefor will be undefined.